# Number of ways of counting nothing is one?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is something that I routinely err in while solving problems. How do we decide what is the value of a recursive function when the argument is at the lowest extreme. An example will help:

> Given n, find the number of ways to tile a 3xN grid using 2x1 blocks only. Rotation of blocks is allowed.

The DP solution is easily found as

> f(n): the number of ways of tiling a 3xN grid
>
> g(n): the number of ways of tiling a 3xN grid with a 1x1 block cut off at the rightmost column
>
> f(n) = f(n-2) + 2*g(n-1)
>
> g(n) = f(n-1) + g(n-2)

I initially thought that the base cases would be f(0)=0, g(0)=0, f(1)=0, g(1)=1. However, this yields a wrong answer. I then read somewhere that f(0)=1 and reasoned it out as

> The number of ways of tiling a 3x0 grid is one because there is only one way we cannot use any tiles(2x1 blocks).

My question is, by that logic, shouldn't g(0) be also one. But, in the correct solution, g(0)=0. In general, when can we say that **the number of ways of using nothing is one**?

Comment: I liked the question! It was more of a "How to think?" question. The ones I like the most in problem-solving.

Comment: I feel like this belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Your functions `f` and `g` are ill-defined at zero. Start at n = 1

Comment: @ColonelPanic: I don't think so. Although you may be easier using n = 1 as your base case, using n = 0 as the base works as well. Take a look at my answer, and let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SeMeKh: You could also find values for `f(-1)` and `g(-1)` that "work", but that does not mean they are well-defined. In this case it is simplest just to start from n=1.

Comment: @Nemo It is perhaps simplest to start at n=1 but then we would also need to define the function for one higher value of n and technically, that is not a base case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your specific question of tiling, think this way:

- How many ways are there to "tile a 3*0 grid"?
  I would say: Just one way, don't do anything! and you can't "do nothing" any other way. (f(0) = 1)
- How many ways are there to "tile a 3*0 grid, cutting that specific block off"?
  I would say: Hey! That's impossible! You can't cut the specific block off since there is nothing. So, there's no way one can solve the task anyhow. (g(0) = 0)

Now, let's get to the general case:

- There's no "general" rule about zero cases.
- Depending on your problem, you may be able to somehow "interpret" the situation, and find the reasonable value. **Most of the times** (depending on your definition of "ways") number of ways of doing "nothing" is 1, and number of ways of doing something impossible is 0!
- Warning! Being able to somehow "interpret" the zero case is not enough for the relation to be correct! You should recheck your recursive relation (i.e. the way you get the n-th value from the previous ones) to be applicable for the zero-to-one case as well, since most of the time this would be a "tricky" case.
- You may find it easier to base your recursive relation on some non-zero case, if you find the zero-case being tricky, or confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, `g(0)` is **invalid**, since there is no way to cut a 1x1 block out of a 3x0 grid.

Invalid values are typically represented as 0, `-∞` or `∞`, but this largely depends on the problem. The number of ways to place something would make sense to be 0 to represent invalid values (otherwise your counts will be off). When working with `min`, you'd generally use `∞`. When working with `max`, you'd generally use `-∞` (or possibly 0).

Generally, the **number of ways** to place 0 objects or objects in a 0-sized space **makes sense to be 1** (i.e. placing no objects) (so `f(0) = 1`). In a lot of other cases **valid** values would be 0.

But these are far from rules (and **avoid blindly following rules**, because you'll get hurt with exceptions); the best advice I can give - when in doubt, **throw a few values in and see what happens**.

In this case you can easily determine what the actual values for g(1), f(1), g(2) and f(2) should be, and use these to calculate g(0) and f(0):

```
g(1) = 1  
f(1) = 0  

g(2): (all invalid, since ? is not populated)
  |X  |X  ?X
  |?  ||  --
  --  ?|  --

g(2) = 0, thus g(0) = 0 - f(1) = 0 - 0 = 0  

f(2):
  ||  --  --
  ||  --  ||
  --  --  ||

f(2) = 3, thus f(0) = 3 - 2*g(1) = 3 - 2 = 1
```